# How can I set specific directory for different users in proftp?

Tags: ftp, chroot, proftpd, symlink, home-directory

Currently, when user A logs in proftp, he comes at his home directory /home/A, when user B logs in proftp, he comes at his home directory /home/B. I want to let user A come at /dir1 and let user B come at /dir2, how can I do in proftpd's configuration file?

Comment: Symlinks could help, even if not applicavle to all situations... https://askubuntu.com/a/41201/638590

Comment: @OldFart That works! Thank you!

Comment: It certainly isn't a 'solution' as it can increase confusion in the long run and with future server updates or worse, migrations. symlinks/hardlinks will almost always work as either a GREAT workaround or a very CRUDE and dodgy one. Workaround nonetheless when it comes down to this specific situation. 

Bounty them points to whomever's solution i pasted - felt it was best to paste something that was relevant rather than just add 'try symlinking'. Anyways, glad it worked out, edit your question to add your solution for further reference...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the home directory for each user in the proftpd configuration file. To do this, you would need to add a `DefaultRoot` directive to the configuration file, specifying the directory that each user should be placed in upon login. For example:

```
# This directive specifies the directory that user A should be placed in
# upon login.
<User A>
  DefaultRoot /dir1
</User A>

# This directive specifies the directory that user B should be placed in
# upon login.
<User B>
  DefaultRoot /dir2
</User B>
```

You would then need to restart the proftpd service in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I cannot start proftpd with the <User> directive: fatal: unknown configuration directive '<User>'. There does exist a line in proftpd.conf: "User nobody", but that means "Set the user that the server runs as nobody".

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by TheTanadu did not work for me either.
What it worked was this:

```
DefaultRoot /backup/usera userAgroup
DefaultRoot /mydir userBgroup
DefaultRoot /upload
```

So whenever a member of the group userAgroup connects, it will upload to /backup/usera.
For members of userBgroup, the upload dir is going to be /mydir.
For anyone else, the upload will go to /upload.